# Android Gallery photo picker like in Messenger app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gallery

I want to implement gallery photo picker similar to what Messenger is using.

That means I dont want to open fullscreen gallery but only small window at the bottom of the screen with photos in grid. Is this possible with native support or it is completely custom design?

I'm using standard intent to access gallery. But someone consider standard gallery access which behaves and looks like in Messenger app.

Gallery Intent:

```
private fun openGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        a.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it yourself with a bottomsheet dialog or you can just use this library
https://github.com/kroegerama/bottomsheet-imagepicker

Answer (score -1):

[FishBun](https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun) is a flexible library to create a gallery in your application.

It also supports various visual styles and allows fine-tuning for details.

Just implement this in your build.gradle file

```
repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
// Under the Android Plugin 3.0.0. 
compile 'com.sangcomz:FishBun:0.10.0'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
or
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

// Android plugin 3.0.0 or higher.
implementation 'com.sangcomz:FishBun:0.11.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
or
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

}
```

and to allow the following permissions in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

To create a basic gallery use the following code:

```
FishBun.with(WithActivityActivity.this)
    .setImageAdapter(new GlideAdapter())
    .startAlbum();
```